# Does there exist an automatic tool to check whether a Python package supports Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a list of Python packages, like e.g. the following

```
appdirs
appnope
Babel
backports-abc
billiard
blinker
cached-property
```

is there some tool I can run on the list to see whether they support Python 3.x? Ideal would be to get which versions of them support Python 3.x, but that's not necessary.

Note: This is just a small part of the packages I need to check on, just to give an example.